# Keyboard does not show language switch button (globe) with UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have 2 UITextField in one UIViewController.

The first one is email. When it got focus, the keyboard will show with language switch button(globe).
[image: EMail UITextField with Keyboard]

The second one is Nickname. When it got focus, the keyboard will show without globe button.
[image: Nickaame UITextField with Keyboard]

The codes between these two UITextField are almost the same. Even if I changed Nickname UITextField to the keyboard type as email UITextField, it won't show globe button. I don't know why the second UITextField will always not show globe button.

The code is as below:

```
        mEmail = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: PADDING,
                                           y: innerY,
                                           width: mInputArea!.bounds.width - PADDING*2,
                                           height: 40))
        mEmail!.textContentType = .emailAddress
        mEmail!.autocapitalizationType = .none
        mEmail!.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        mEmail!.layer.borderColor = ColorDef.background.cgColor
        mEmail!.layer.borderWidth = 1
        mEmail!.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        mEmail!.placeholder = localizedInfoPlist("Account_Email")
        mEmail!.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        mEmail!.returnKeyType = .next
        mEmail!.delegate = self
        mInputArea!.addSubview(mEmail!)
        innerY += (PADDING + mEmail!.bounds.height)

        mName = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: PADDING,
                                          y: innerY,
                                          width: mEmail!.bounds.width,
                                          height: mEmail!.bounds.height))
        mName!.textContentType = .nickname
        mName!.autocapitalizationType = .none
        mName!.keyboardType = .default
        mName!.layer.borderColor = ColorDef.background.cgColor
        mName!.layer.borderWidth = 1
        mName!.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        mName!.placeholder = localizedInfoPlist("Nickname")
        mName!.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        mName!.returnKeyType = .next
        mName!.delegate = self
        mInputArea!.addSubview(mName!)
        innerY += (PADDING + mEmail!.bounds.height)
```

How can I do to get the globe button in Keyboard with Nickname UITextField?

Comment: try changing the values of `mName!.keyboardType = .default` from `.default` to some other available choices and see the results.

Comment: I have change it to .twitter, .emailaddress ... not work.

Comment: I found when I exchange the two UITextFields' Position, the globe button is still shown with "Upper" UITextField. It's so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my soft keyboards are English and Gboard (Google Keyboard). 
The globe button won't show when the second UITextField is focused.
I think it might be the problem that Gboard is not count as other language keyboard iPhone did. So I add other language with "Apple iPhone Keyboard" then it shows the globe button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mName: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        mEmail!.textContentType = .emailAddress
        mEmail!.autocapitalizationType = .none
        mEmail!.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        mEmail!.layer.borderWidth = 1
        mEmail!.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        mEmail!.placeholder = "Account_Email"
        mEmail!.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        mEmail!.returnKeyType = .next
        mEmail!.delegate = self

        mName!.textContentType = .nickname
        mName!.autocapitalizationType = .none
        mName!.keyboardType = .default
        mName!.layer.borderWidth = 1
        mName!.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        mName!.placeholder = "Nickname"
        mName!.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        mName!.returnKeyType = .next
        mName!.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        switch textField
        {
        case self.mEmail:
            self.mName.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        default:
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I add the block in textFieldShouldReturn you write, but nothing changed. I code UI without storyboard. Maybe this is why the problem happened?